# inputText inside a cellEditor update the form when the inputText lost the focus

Tags: primefaces

The inputText inside the cellEditor updates the form when the inputText lost the focus and I need that the form is updated when I press the ENTER key

```
<p:dataTable editable="true" editMode="cell" rowKey="#{invoice.key}"
selection="#{invoiceBB.invoiceSelected}" selectionMode="single"
value="#{invoiceBB.listaDetalleinvoice}" var="invoice">
    <p:column>
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{invoice.price}">
                    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2"
                        type="number" />
                </h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText
                    onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {onchange(); return false;}"
                    style="width: 500px !important;" value="#{invoice.price}">
                    <p:ajax event="change"
                        listener="#{invoiceBB.updatePrice}"
                        update="@form" />
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

But if I put the inputText out the dataTable, it updates the form correctly when I press the ENTER button

```
<p:inputText
    onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {onchange(); return false;}"
    style="width: 500px !important;" value="#{invoice.price}">
    <p:ajax event="change"
        listener="#{invoiceBB.updatePrice}"
        update="@form" />
</p:inputText>
```

Is there a fix to do this when the inputText is inside the cellEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry my bad.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("keydown", ".ui-cell-editor-input input", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        someName(); 
    }
});
</script>
   <p:remoteCommand name="someName" process="@this" update="@form" actionListener="#{invoiceBB.updatePrice}"/>
```

Comment: I do not need to test this code becouse it works, it is a typo update="@Form" with update="@form" . thx i learned something

Comment: Yes, you need to test this code, as my example, it works outside the cellEditor, but inside the cellEditor. I fix the typo before I asked if you tested the code. Thanks for your support

Comment: Changed the answer, and tested uh :)

Comment: How I know which row of the datatable fired the remoteCommand?

Comment: In front JS or in back bean? When a row is generated in dataTable it gets an attribute data-ri="0 for first row and its value 0, for beack bean  <p:dataTable rowIndexVar="rowId" <f:param name="id" value="#{rowId}" />

Comment: Where I put the `<f:param name="id" value="#{rowId}" />` sentence? And How can I use the id value?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/

Comment: I dit that but I get a null value :S

Comment: look please: `<f:facet name="input">
 <p:inputText style="width: 500px !important;"
  value="#{invoice.price}">
  <f:param name="id" value="#{index}" />
 </p:inputText>
</f:facet>` and the datatable: `<p:dataTable ... rowIndexVar="index" ... >`